# non compactness of a subset of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

How to show that the set $$\{(x,y):x^3+y^3=1\}$$ is not compact?

I dont know what to do?

Comment: It is closed. So you could try to prove that it is not bounded?

Comment: Do you know what the graph is?

Comment: Note that, "A subset S of a metric space (M, d) is bounded if it is contained in a ball of finite radius".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You may know that a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ which is not bounded is not compact. If you don't know it, then prove it first. (The stronger claim, that a subset $\mathbb R^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded is true but not needed here). Is the set you are considering bounded?